# C# accessdenied exception reading a logfile in appdata

Tags: c#

bashing my head against the wall with this one, tried adding an app manifest and elevating, but whenever my program tries to read c:\users\username\appdata\roaming\microsoft\teams\logs.txt
it throws an exception.
If I use PowerShell, I can read this file with no permissions issues.

Edit - what is interesting is if I compare the security of two folders at the same level, s ay the Excel Folder and the teams folder under /appdata/roaming/Microsoft. Both are identical, and I can access the Excel one but not the teams one. Even Elevating does not help. Yet outside of Visual Studio, I can browse and access these paths quite happily as a user..

Here is the code snippet:

```
        private static string GetTeamsLog()
    {
        string homeDir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
        // Code to read the log files and return the contents as a string
        // Path to the log file(s)
        string logPath = homeDir + @"\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Teams\";
        string logFile = logPath + "logs.txt";
        string log = "";
        try
        {
            if (!File.Exists(logFile))
            {
                throw new FileNotFoundException("The log file was not found.");
            }

            if ((File.GetAttributes(logFile) & FileAttributes.ReadOnly) == FileAttributes.ReadOnly)
            {
                throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("The application doesn't have the necessary permissions to access the file.");
            }

            if (Path.GetFullPath(logFile).Length > 260)
            {
                throw new PathTooLongException("The specified path is too long.");
            }

            if (!DriveInfo.GetDrives().FirstOrDefault(x => x.RootDirectory.Name == Path.GetPathRoot(logFile)).IsReady)
            {
                throw new DriveNotFoundException("The specified drive is not valid or not ready.");
            }

            // Read the contents of the log file
            log = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(logFile);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        return log;
    }
```

The error triggered by log = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(logfile);  is

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path 'C:\Users\jimmy\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Teams\logs.txt' is denied.'
This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
        Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.CreateFile(string, System.IO.FileMode, System.IO.FileAccess, System.IO.FileShare, System.IO.FileOptions)
        Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(string, System.IO.FileMode, System.IO.FileAccess, System.IO.FileShare, System.IO.FileOptions, long, System.IO.UnixFileMode?)
        System.IO.Strategies.OSFileStreamStrategy.OSFileStreamStrategy(string, System.IO.FileMode, System.IO.FileAccess, System.IO.FileShare, System.IO.FileOptions, long, System.IO.UnixFileMode?)
        System.IO.Strategies.FileStreamHelpers.ChooseStrategyCore(string, System.IO.FileMode, System.IO.FileAccess, System.IO.FileShare, System.IO.FileOptions, long, System.IO.UnixFileMode?)
        System.IO.StreamReader.ValidateArgsAndOpenPath(string, System.Text.Encoding, int)
        System.IO.File.ReadAllText(string, System.Text.Encoding)
        TeamsMonitor.Form1.GetTeamsLog() in Form1.cs
```

Comment: Try to terminate Teams and try again. Teams might open the log file so that other processes cannot access it while Teams is running

Comment: Unfortunately, that would break the app, its monitoring for status changes in the logs realtime

Comment: Yes, but perform the test so that we know whether this is or is not the problem.

Comment: Yes, even with Teams closed, the error persists

Comment: What type of Application do you have? .net Framework? .net Core? UWP? Can you open the text file in notepad.exe?

Comment: its a .net7 winforms application, yes, I can open the file in notepad no problem

Comment: Have you tested the code independent from the change notification? The file might only be locked shortly after the notification is generated.

Comment: Could you please try running your program as Administrator and see if it produces the same exception?

Comment: That was already tried..

Answer (score 0):

It might be used by Teams. So read it this way:

```
using(FileStream logFileStream = new FileStream(logFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    using(StreamReader logFileReader = new StreamReader(logFileStream))
    {
        string text = logFileReader.ReadToEnd();
        // Your code..
    }
}
```

Comment: Sadly that throws the same error

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, it appears Acronis Cyber Protect was messing with the permissions. Even though the "protection" was disabled, the Acronis Cyber Protect service was still running. Once killed, I no longer had any issues.